# Beneficiary's current address while filing for I 130

Tags: usa, greencard

I am filing for my parent's Green Card. At this very time, I am living in the USA and they are also visiting me currently on Visitor's visa.

Now, while filing for their I 130 petition, I am facing a dilemma. There is an entry while filing for I-130 which is asking me `what is their current address?`.

Well, technically speaking, they have a house in India and the house in India is their address. However, though, it can also be thought that since they are living with me for a couple of months here in the United States, My American address is their current address.

On one hand, I would prefer to put American address as their current address because, if USCIS is going to send any documents, then I prefer that they send all the docs here to my address and then I can respond to them quickly if there are any queries. On the other hand, if it can be considered inaccurate then I am fine putting their address in India as their current address.

Any guidance in this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're in the USA as a visitor, that is, on a temporary basis. Their address is in India where they permanently live.

My answer above is assuming that you're not filing for their adjustment of status (I-485).

If you are, use an US address and be aware that it might be difficult to prove that your parents came to the US with the intention to stay temporarily and then decided to stay permanently.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So just to understand  your comments above, you are suggesting to use their address in India as their current address both for I-130 and I-485. Is that correct understanding?

Comment: @Lost: No, he is suggesting that if you are filing I-130 and I-485, then use the US address as their current address since they are now staying in the US permanently.

Comment: @user102008 They are not staying in USA permenently. They are here for 3 months.

Comment: @Lost: If they file I-485, that means they are applying for Adjustment of Status, i.e. to become US permanent residents from within the US, without leaving. In that case, they would be staying in the US permanently.

Comment: @user102008 Thank you for the help!

Comment: @user102008 Thank you for the explaination. That was really helpful.